# Spotbugs maven plugin output in a single XML

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, findbugs, spotbugs

I had run spotbugs using the **spotbugs-maven-plugin** and it creates an XML in **target** folder as **spotbugsXml.xml** when I run the command

> mvn spotbugs:spotbugs

For multi-module projects, the project creates a target/spotbugsXml.xml for every module specified. Is there a way where I can get a single spotbugs xml in the parent build directory?